# use jsoup extract certain part of text

Tags: java, jsoup

I have an webpage with source contains several similar structure like below:

```
<tr>
<td width="10%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font class="bodytext9">1-Jun-2013</font></td>
<td width="4%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align=center><font class="bodytext9">Sat</font></td>
<td width="5%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center"></td>
<td width="5%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center"><font class="bodytext9">Another Text</font></td>
<td width="5%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center"><font class="bodytext9"><img src="img/colors/white.gif"></font></td>
<td width="15%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center"><a class="black_9" href="link2">Here is also Text</a></td>
<td width="15%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center"><a href="LINKtoWeb" class=list><u>STRING TO CAPTURE</u></a></td>
<td width="4%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center"><a target="_new" href="AnotherLink"><img src="img/img2.gif" border="0"></a></td>
</tr>
```

This kind of structure repeated many time with different text inside, but I only want to extract this set because the text "STRING TO CAPTURE" appear here FIRST TIME. So how do I use Jsoup to extract only this set, and the visible text between it, as well as the url

```
AnotherLink
```

at the line of the text "STRING TO CAPTURE" appears ?
I am new to Jsoup, so I only tried this

```
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.website.com").get();

Element link = doc.select("a").first();
String relHref = link.attr("href"); 
String absHref = link.attr("abs:href"); 
String text = doc.body().text();
String linkHref = link.attr("href"); 
String linkText = link.text(); 

  System.out.println("link:" + link);
  System.out.println("text:" + text);
```

but cant do it in advance for this purpose, please give me some advices ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this test input:

```
String test = "<html><body><table>";
test += "<tr>";
test += "<td width=\"10%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\"><font class=\"bodytext9\">1-Jun-2013</font></td>";
test += "<td width=\"4%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=center><font class=\"bodytext9\">Sat</font></td>";
test += "<td width=\"5%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"></td>";
test += "<td width=\"5%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><font class=\"bodytext9\">Another Text</font></td>";
test += "<td width=\"5%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><font class=\"bodytext9\"><img src=\"img/colors/white.gif\"></font></td>";
test += "<td width=\"15%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><a class=\"black_9\" href=\"link2\">Here is also Text</a></td>";
test += "<td width=\"15%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><a href=\"LINKtoWeb\" class=list><u>TEXT THAT DOESN'T MATCH</u></a></td>";
test += "<td width=\"4%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><a target=\"_new\" href=\"NotMatchLink\"><img src=\"img/img2.gif\" border=\"0\"></a></td>";
test += "</tr>";
test += "<tr>";
test += "<td width=\"10%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\"><font class=\"bodytext9\">1-Jun-2013</font></td>";
test += "<td width=\"4%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=center><font class=\"bodytext9\">Sat</font></td>";
test += "<td width=\"5%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"></td>";
test += "<td width=\"5%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><font class=\"bodytext9\">Another Text</font></td>";
test += "<td width=\"5%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><font class=\"bodytext9\"><img src=\"img/colors/white.gif\"></font></td>";
test += "<td width=\"15%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><a class=\"black_9\" href=\"link2\">Here is also Text</a></td>";
test += "<td width=\"15%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><a href=\"LINKtoWeb\" class=list><u>STRING TO CAPTURE</u></a></td>";
test += "<td width=\"4%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><a target=\"_new\" href=\"AnotherLink\"><img src=\"img/img2.gif\" border=\"0\"></a></td>";
test += "</tr>";
test += "<tr>";
test += "<td width=\"10%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\"><font class=\"bodytext9\">1-Jun-2013</font></td>";
test += "<td width=\"4%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=center><font class=\"bodytext9\">Sat</font></td>";
test += "<td width=\"5%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"></td>";
test += "<td width=\"5%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><font class=\"bodytext9\">Another Text</font></td>";
test += "<td width=\"5%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><font class=\"bodytext9\"><img src=\"img/colors/white.gif\"></font></td>";
test += "<td width=\"15%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><a class=\"black_9\" href=\"link2\">Here is also Text</a></td>";
test += "<td width=\"15%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><a href=\"LINKtoWeb\" class=list><u>MORE TEXT THAT DOESN'T MATCH</u></a></td>";
test += "<td width=\"4%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><a target=\"_new\" href=\"NotMatchLink\"><img src=\"img/img2.gif\" border=\"0\"></a></td>";
test += "</tr>";
test += "<tr>";
test += "<td width=\"10%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\"><font class=\"bodytext9\">1-Jun-2013</font></td>";
test += "<td width=\"4%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=center><font class=\"bodytext9\">Sat</font></td>";
test += "<td width=\"5%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"></td>";
test += "<td width=\"5%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><font class=\"bodytext9\">Another Text</font></td>";
test += "<td width=\"5%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><font class=\"bodytext9\"><img src=\"img/colors/white.gif\"></font></td>";
test += "<td width=\"15%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><a class=\"black_9\" href=\"link2\">Here is also Text</a></td>";
test += "<td width=\"15%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><a href=\"LINKtoWeb\" class=list><u>STILL MORE TEXT THAT DOESN'T MATCH</u></a></td>";
test += "<td width=\"4%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><a target=\"_new\" href=\"NotMatchLink\"><img src=\"img/img2.gif\" border=\"0\"></a></td>";
test += "</tr>";
test += "</table></body></html>";
test += "<td width=\"10%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\"><font class=\"bodytext9\">Second 1-Jun-2013</font></td>";
test += "<td width=\"4%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=center><font class=\"bodytext9\">Second Sat</font></td>";
test += "<td width=\"5%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"></td>";
test += "<td width=\"5%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><font class=\"bodytext9\">Second Another Text</font></td>";
test += "<td width=\"5%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><font class=\"bodytext9\"><img src=\"img/colors/white.gif\"></font></td>";
test += "<td width=\"15%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><a class=\"black_9\" href=\"link2\">Second Here is also Text</a></td>";
test += "<td width=\"15%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><a href=\"LINKtoWeb\" class=list><u>STRING TO CAPTURE</u></a></td>";
test += "<td width=\"4%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" align=\"center\"><a target=\"_new\" href=\"SecondAnotherLink\"><img src=\"img/img2.gif\" border=\"0\"></a></td>";
test += "</tr>";
```

And this code:

```
final Document document = Jsoup.parse(test);
final Element entireRow = document.select("tr:contains(STRING TO CAPTURE)").get(0);
for (final Element column : entireRow.select("td")) {
    System.out.println("Column text is: " + column.text());
}
final Elements link = entireRow.select("td:contains(STRING TO CAPTURE) + td > a[href]");
System.out.println("Target link is: " + link.attr("href"));
```

It outputs:

```
Column text is: 1-Jun-2013
Column text is: Sat
Column text is: 
Column text is: Another Text
Column text is: 
Column text is: Here is also Text
Column text is: STRING TO CAPTURE
Column text is: 
Target link is: AnotherLink
```

Comment: At first, I cannot extract the single group that you input to test above! As I said, that structure repeat several time in the web, so I need to find a way to extract the first group that contain "STRING TO CAPTURE" the first time read from beginning to the end of the source code; then I need to extract each visible text on each line separately, and one more is the link in the line that has "STRING TO CAPTURE"

Comment: So by group do you mean the `tr` and by each line do you mean each `td`?

Comment: I've updated my answer based on that guess in my prior comment.

Comment: It is almost there, but the problem is the "STRING TO CAPTURE" will repeat in another structure too, so using this, it will extract from all structure repeated below, I want to get the first structure that it appears only

Comment: I made the change to get the first one only and updated the sample to demonstrate it.

Comment: For real case, I need to use: Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.website.com").get(); but it will not feed the next command, requires elements found: element; You have any idea? May be not .get() ?

Comment: What do you mean by "will not feed the next command"? Is the request not returning anything or is the `select` not matching anything? If the former, it is likely a connectivity/request issue. The latter would require looking into the actual contents of the `Document` to see what the request is returning. What does the URL return when you look at it in a web browser?

Comment: I need to change the next command to "final Element entireRow..." withous 's" at the end of 'Element'. It works! Thanks a lot for your support !!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30917/discussion-between-user1314404-and-laz)

Comment: If you able to help pls give me some more minutes!
I need to solve the problem a little bit further!
my website actually a little bit unstructure
when I tried, I find out, the <tr> and <td> is not only open and close for that structures, but it open and close out side all of them also
which will returns all the text in the website if using your code
while it should only return the "nearest" <tr> and <td> surrounding that "STRING TO CAPTURE"

Comment: Ok, I found solution, just use .get(i) behind it and increase i from 0 until get the exact result ! :)