# how can I fetch outer div text only with JSoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="description">
    <div class='daterange'>
        Hello 
     <span itemprop='startDate'>
        June 3, 2011
     </span>
    </div>
    This is some description <i>that</i> I want to fetch
 </div><br/>
```

and I want to extract only the part:

```
This is some description <i>that</i> I want to fetch
```

How can I do it with jsoup?

I tried using `String description = doc.select("div.description").text()` but then I'm getting all content that's inside.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is creating a String which will hold the words of the html file.
this is made by the following code, doc.body().text() is taking the text without all the html tags.

```
`public String getWords(String url) {
        String text = "";
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            text = doc.body().text();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return text;
    }
`
```

Comment: Hm, but I think that your approach will also extract `Hello` and `June 3, 2011`, and I want to avoid that

Comment: I think I found the solution for your question, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835878/use-jsoup-extract-certain-part-of-text

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String description = doc.select("div").remove().first().html();
```

Comment: it works with this exact html snippet. Post the complete html page if its not too big